# python: need a deepcopy equivalent breaking all shared identity

Tags: python, deep-copy

Due to some constrains I need to create a fresh copy of an object alongwith fresh copies of all its attributes and for attributes of its attributes and so on recursively.

Existing deepcopy() is recursive, but when multiple objects within the tree being copied have the same starting identity, they also have the same ending identity (even though their ending identities don't match their starting identities).

For the following case:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x

v = A(1)
o = [v, v]
```

copy.deepcopy does following:

```
dc_o = copy.deepcopy(o)
assert dc_o[0] is not o[0] # new identity from the original
assert dc_o[0] is dc_o[1]  # but maintains identity within the copied tree
assert dc_o[0] == dc_o[1]  # ...as well as value
```

But, what I need is:

```
r_dc_o = recursive_deepcopy(o)
assert r_dc_o[0] is not o[0]      # new identity from the original
assert r_dc_o[0] is not r_dc_o[1] # also new identity from elsewhere inside copy
assert r_dc_o[0] == r_dc_o[1]     # while maintaining the same value
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Equivalent lists compare equal even if they are not the same list.  Try comparing with `is`/`is not` instead of `==`/`!=`.

Comment: `1` and `2` will *always* be the same object; they're interned. `deepcopy` is always recursive; you're just not testing in a way that demonstrates that.

Comment: Sorry my test case is wrong, i'm fixing it.

Comment: Fixed it.. really sorry for the cofusion due to wrong test case!

Comment: What you're asking for is a dangerous semantic -- rather than simply ensuring that anything in the new structure is distinct from everything in the old structure, ensuring that everything in the new tree is also distinct from every other part of that object tree means that you couldn't do a deepcopy of anything that had internal references without breaking them. Think about if you have an object that has a "parent" link/backreference - a deepcopy that ensured no identity between immutable objects would have children whose "parent" link pointed to a third object that wasn't their actual parent!

Comment: Incidentally, the module documentation goes into these issues, and explains both reasoning and implementation behind its behavior. Reading https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html is probably a good idea.

Comment: Fixed the code.. it was a typo.

Comment: Updated the answer to address the question as amended. I cannot emphasize enough how much a Really Really Bad Idea this is. Much better to override `__deepcopy__` on the specific layers where you need this semantic.

Comment: I've tried to clarify the question based on the new code and comments to be a bit more directly clear about what you're trying to accomplish. Hopefully this is an improvement?

Answer (score 2):

Fully automating a recursive deepcopy in a way that *didn't* memoize objects would be extremely dangerous -- it would mean you couldn't have any kind of objects with internal references preserved in a way that would make those references useful after the copy operation (think about objects with a "parent" link, or objects that link to a shared registry or similar resource). That said, if you really wanted to do this (and you shouldn't -- it **will** break a great many objects passed through the operation), you can accomplish it by constructing a memo dictionary that ignored attempts at adding keys, and passing that as a second argument to `deepcopy()`.

So, here we are:

```
import copy

class baddict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        pass

class A:
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x
  def __eq__(self, other):
    self.x == other.x

v = A(1)
o = [v, v]
r_dc_o = copy.deepcopy(o, baddict())
assert r_dc_o[0] is not r_dc_o[1]
assert r_dc_o[0] == r_dc_o[1]
```

I'd suggest thinking about *why* you need this behavior, and trying to come up with a better way to accomplish it. Even a `baddict` implementation that looked at the value and skipped memoizing only if values were instances of a specific class would be safer than what we're doing here.

Comment: Hi Charles, sorry for the wrong test case before. I have fixed the test case now. I hope it clarifies my question now.

Comment: Ahh. Yup, that clarifies your question quite a bit.